# Подскажите, как сделать так чтобы программа срабатывала заново?

Tags: java

Java изучаю буквально пару дней, ещё толком ничего не знаю, сидел решал задачу и в голову пришла мысль почему бы не написать программку которая будет выкидывать 2 рандомно сгенерированных числа и просить ответ, всё сделал, но встретился с проблемой.
После того как я ввожу ответ программа говорит "правильно" или "не правильно" и после чего просто заканчивает свою работу. Мне нужно сделать так чтобы программа вновь выдавала 2 числа и просила ответ.
Пожалуйста объясните как это можно сделать?
Код прилагаю.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] array;
        array = new int[2];

        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            array[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        }

        int a = array[0];
        int b = array[1];
        int c = a + b;
        System.out.println("\nВведите ответ:\n");
        System.out.println(array[0] + " + " + array[1] + " = ");


        int input = in.nextInt();

        if (c == input){
            System.out.println("Правильно");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Не правильно");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `do { ваша программа } while (ваше условаие завершения программы)`

Answer (score 0):

Сделать так, чтобы программа постоянно выдавала 2 случайных числа нельзя. Точнее можно, но это будет бесконечный цикл и программа не завершит свою работу самостоятельно. С помощью цикла while можно добавить условие, например, если количество правильных ответов равняется 5, то завершить выполнение. Для этого нужно будет создать переменную int counter (например), которая будет хранить значение кол-ва правильных ответов.

Проще говоря, вам нужно написать код с таким условием, чтобы программа могла понять, когда ей нужно остановится.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш цикл for присваивает положительные числа...
могу предложить вариант do while. Пример кода.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestMain {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input;
    int[] array;
    array = new int[2];

        do {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                array[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            }

            int a = array[0];
            int b = array[1];
            int c = a + b;
            System.out.println("\nВведите ответ:\n");
            System.out.println(array[0] + " + " + array[1] + " = ");


            input = in.nextInt();

            if (c == input) {
                System.out.println("Правильно");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Не правильно");
            }
        } while(input > 0 );

}
```

}

.т.е. пока твои ответы больше 0 - цикл будет повторяться. как только надоест введи отрицательное число (-1 к примеру) программа выдаст "не правильно" и завершится.
тут еще важно объявить переменную input до цикла. (почитай про области видимости).
Условия можете придумывать сами, на что фантазии хватит))